# Loop thru the dataset and get yearly average

Tags: loops, excel, average, vba

The excel file has 20 tabs. Each tab has over 2000 rows of daily forward curves. The layout of the data on each tab: the first column is the date 2007-01-01, 2007-01-02, 2007-01-03.. and the first row is 2008-01-01, 2008-02-01,2008-03-1 all the way to 2025-12-01

Is there a way to loop through all the row and return the average price of Y+1, Y+2, Y+3 for each day in the first column?

Comment: Yes there is! [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Give it a shot, maybe try the macro recorder, then post your code and the specific spot that is generating problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way, but this is how I would do it. Make a new sheet with whatever formatting you want (ie. by day of the year or whatever). Once you have that, in column B next to the January 1, type `=average(` Then use the shortcut `CTRL+PgDown` to switch tabs from left to right. Click the first day entry on the first year, then press the `,` key, then use `CTRL+PgDown` (I use the right `CTRL` key with my left hand) to quickly cycle through clicking the first entry again on each tab. After the first comma, you won't have to press it again, so it should be pretty easy.

When you've added the last entry, hit enter and the average for the first day will be there. If you have already done the formatting for each day in column A, just click the cell with the first average. You'll see a small square in the bottom right corner of the cell. Double click it and voila.